# Issue in ldap authintication order

Tags: c#, java, active-directory, ldap

I am using ldap.
If the user account is locked, and I tried to login with this user but with BAD password, I will get the error that the user account is locked.

Is there any way to control the order of authintication . I mean to make it check for the password then the status of user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't imagine you can change this by configuration. In any case if the account is locked, all passwords are bad.

You need to consider whether or not to disclose the account-locked information to the user, which is an information leakage that the account exists, which an attacker may be able to profit by, by now keeping the username constant and just trying different passwords, but the LDAP server should be protected against that, or protect itself.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to know if the entered password is correct even if the user account is locked or not ?

You can "validate" password, then know if the user is unlocked. Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23013070/922977) to have a code sample.

Then, you can move on your operation.

Comment: do you mean that this code:
return pc.ValidateCredentials(strUsername_, strPassword_);
will return false if the password is wrong ?

Comment: May I know the reason of the downvote ?  Yeah, ValidateCredentials returns false if the clear string text is not correct, true otherwise.